# Date format conversion using d3.js

Tags: d3.js

As my first exploration in D3.js,there is a datefield in the csv defined as '01/12/2016'.how to convert this to a proper d3.TimeFormat ?

Comment: What you want is to parse a string. Therefore, you need a parser (`d3.timeParse`), not a formatter: https://jsfiddle.net/p968Loay/

Answer (score -1):

Your Format  is DD/MM/YYYY(01/12/2016)

Use the Following d3 time Format

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y").parse;
parseDate('YOUR DATE FORMAT');
```

Comment: is it possible to convert using the above as Dec 2016.